# Erro Illegal group reference

Tags: java, regex, replace

Está estourando um erro em um `replace` que estou fazendo.
A string em questão é essa:

```
<table id='tablecritica' class='table table-bordered table-hover'>      <tbody>  <tr>   <td> Valor Contábil (R$) </td>      <td style='text-align: right;'> 1.076,63 </td>  </tr> <tr class='fundo total table-secondary'>      <td> Total A (R$) </td>     <td> 1.076,63 </td>  </tr> <tr style='font-weight: bold'>   <td> Comparativo </td>      <td style='text-align: right;'> <> </td>  </tr> <tr>    <td> Base de Cálculo (R$) </td>     <td style='text-align: right;'> 0,00 </td>  </tr> <tr>      <td> Isenta Não Tributada (R$) </td>    <td style='text-align: right;'> 0,00 </td>  </tr> <tr>      <td> Outras (R$) </td>      <td style='text-align: right;'> 1.076,63 </td>  </tr> <tr>      <td> Imposto Retido ST (R$) </td>   <td style='text-align: right;'> 0,00 </td>  </tr> <tr>      <td> Imposto Retido Subs. ST (R$) </td>     <td style='text-align: right;'> 0,00 </td>  </tr> <tr>      <td> Outros Impostos (R$) </td>     <td style='text-align: right;'> 0,00 </td>  </tr> <tr class='fundo total table-secondary'>      <td> Total B (R$) </td>     <td> 1.076,63 </td>  </tr>   </tbody>     </table>
```

Estou enviando esse script como parâmetro para um template HTML, onde eu leio o HTML e só replico os parâmetros.

```
Hashtable valuesReplace = new Hashtable();
valuesReplace.put("Tabelacritica",  gb.nullToEmpty(  tabelaCritica ));

Hashtable hashReplace = (Hashtable) valuesReplace;

String templateEmail = gb.getPropertyAplication("Path") + "/" + templateName;

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        java.io.File file = new java.io.File(templateEmail);  

        java.io.FileInputStream fileInputStream = new java.io.FileInputStream( file );
        java.io.BufferedReader bufferedReader = new java.io.BufferedReader( new java.io.InputStreamReader(fileInputStream) );

        while ( ( row = bufferedReader.readLine() ) != null ) {

            row = new String(row.trim().getBytes(), "UTF-8");    
            stringBuilder.append( row );

        }             

        String contentEmail = stringBuilder.toString();        
        String str;
        java.util.Enumeration keys = hashReplace.keys();

        while(keys.hasMoreElements()) {

            str = (String) keys.nextElement();

            contentEmail = contentEmail.replaceAll("\\{" + str + "\\}", hashReplace.get(str).toString());   

        }
```

Se eu mando qualquer outro parâmetro como string funciona normalmente.

Comment: Algumas dicas não diretamente relacionadas ao `replace`: `Hashtable` está obsoleta, prefira usar `HashMap` (ou qualquer outra [implementação de `Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html)). Das próximas vezes, procure deixar o exemplo mais sucinto, somente com o necessário (por exemplo, seu código tem leitura de um arquivo que não sabemos o que é, e não parece relevante para o problema) - tente fazer um **[mcve]** ⭠ leia este link, tem muitas dicas para fazer um exemplo que não dependa de recursos externos (como arquivos) e ajuda muito quem for responder...

Comment: ... nesse caso até deu pra saber a causa do problema, mas nem sempre é assim (se o problema estivesse no conteúdo do arquivo, por exemplo, ninguém conseguiria simular o erro). Por isso é importante tentar fazer um **[mcve]**

Answer (score 2):

O problema é que sua string contém o caractere `$` (em vários trechos, como "Total A (R$)", entre outros).

E no segundo parâmetro do [método `replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) o caractere `$` possui significado especial: ele serve para designar o *match* obtido em um [grupo de captura](http://rexegg.com/regex-capture.html): a sintaxe é `$N`, onde `N` é o número do respectivo grupo (ou seja, `$1`, `$2`, etc).

Mas no seu caso o `$` não está se referindo a nenhum grupo, e sim ao próprio caractere `$`, sem nenhum signficado especial. Sendo assim, você deve fazer o escape do mesmo, usando o [método `Matcher.quoteReplacement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement-java.lang.String-):

```
contentEmail = contentEmail.replaceAll("\\{" + str + "\\}", Matcher.quoteReplacement(hashReplace.get(str).toString()));
```

---

No fundo, o que `quoteReplacement` faz é colocar uma `\` antes do `$`, pois assim ele passa a ser interpretado como um caractere comum, sem significado especial. Mas como suas strings parecem ser grandes, não me parece uma boa fazer esta substituição manualmente. Até porque a [documentação de `replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) menciona que o caractere `\` também sofre deste mesmo problema e precisa ser escapado, então use `quoteReplacement` que já cuida desses detalhes para você (se a string não tiver nenhum `$` ou `\`, por exemplo, ela é retornada sem modificações, então você pode usar para todas as suas strings).